# Is there a bug on category_lists?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, categories

Requests on pages like this https://graph.facebook.com/295212867812 used to return the category_lists, and now they are no longer being returned.  Is this a bug, or some sort of odd expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, going to https://graph.facebook.com/295212867812?fields=category_lists returns :

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Unknown fields: category_lists",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

Even though it's one of the fields you can query in the graph api (found here: developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#fields )

So, could be a bug. or they just simply don't offer it anymore in the graph API for pages.

This however, returns the category for your page:

graph.facebook.com/295212867812?fields=category

Comment: Thanks Keoki for the response.  Professional services is not the category I was trying to get.  The categories that are listed on the actual facebook page of "Bike Shop · Repair Service" are the ones i was trying to get.  This was returned by graph API a few weeks ago in the category_lists, but seems to have disappeared on me.

Answer (score 2):

The category_lists change has been removed from the [July 2013 breaking changes](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/04/03/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/):

> Update April 9, 2013 - **We are removing the following change from this migration**:
>
> Page 'category' field name change
> We are renaming the 'category' field to 'category_lists' for Pages Graph API

So, it sounds like category_lists is gone.

However, it's interesting that querying for category_list (without the s) does return valid data, so maybe it will be officially renamed in the future:

https://graph.facebook.com/295212867812?fields=category_list

```
{
    "id": "295212867812",
    "category_list": [
       {
          "id": 128003127270269,
          "name": "Bike Shop"
       },
       {
          "id": 193198380699462,
          "name": "Repair Service"
       }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Marty Dill's answer, I think this is not really documented yet. At least I didn't find anything for the Graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes) or FQL (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page).

The category_list is also appended to the Graph API response for a user's likes (I just liked your page...). A query for https://graph.facebook.com/123456789/?fields=id,likes (replace 123456789 with your user_id and add an valid access_token) results in

```
{
"id": "123456789",
"likes": {
    "data": [
        {
            "category": "Professional services",
            "category_list": [
                {
                    "id": "128003127270269",
                    "name": "Bike Shop"
                },
                {
                    "id": "193198380699462",
                    "name": "Repair Service"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Bicycle Tech",
            "id": "295212867812",
            "created_time": "2013-05-13T10:19:58+0000"
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/123456789/likes?limit=5000&offset=5000"
    }
}
}
```